# How can I get rid of empty lines Perl's Pod so they don't show up with Pod::Usage?

Tags: perl, documentation-generation, perl-pod

I have following pod which I used with getopt::long:

```
=head1 SYNOPSIS

foo [OPTION]... [URL]...

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 20

=item B<-h, --help>

Print a brief help message and exits.

=item B<-i, --input=FILE>

Reads from FILE

=back

=cut
```

and when I provides -h it produces:

```
Usage:
    foo [OPTION]... [URL]...

Options:
    -h, --help          Print a brief help message and exits.

    -i, --input=FILE    Reads from FILE
```

My question is: how can I remove empty line between -h and -i ?

Comment: I like the extra line. Give us old folks a break. Every year I have to make my terminal font larger!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Pod::Usage` just calls a Pod formatter like `perldoc` or `Text::Pod` to generate the usage messages from your Pod. The Pod code you've written will be formatted with a couple of empty lines by those tools. If you don't want those, write different Pod. For example

```
=over 4

=item B<-h>                     Print a brief help message and exits.

=item B<-i>, B<--input=FILE>    Reads from FILE

=back
```

Unfortunately that won't look as nice when being converted into other formats such as HTML, and you're losing the nice vertical alignment of options and their descriptions. However, as `Pod::Usage` is really intended for command-line programs, it seems to be reasonable to optimise for readability of text on a terminal instead of having things look good in HTML or similar.